# Why network league result showing (+) value of mean difference?

Tags: networking

I work on network meta-analysis project. My study aims to compare the efficacy of some drugs to reduce relieve pain. Small value are desirable using SMD.
From other study, I saw that the netleague result should be (-) result to show the magnitude of pain "reduction".
However, after several trial and error, my netleauge table showing (+) result with the inverted CI value (they should (-) but the result (+), or vice versa).

Those are my syntax in r programming.

```
\#2 pairwise
ssPainDurWF \<- pairwise(treat = t, mean = y, sd = sd, n = n, studlab = study, sm = "SMD", data = ssPainDur)
ssPainDurWF

ssPainDurNMA \<- netmeta(TE = TE, seTE = seTE, treat1 = treat1, treat2 = treat2,
studlab = studlab, sm = "SMD", data = ssPainDurWF,
small.values = "desirable",
fixed = FALSE, random = TRUE,
sep.trts = "vs",
reference.group = "Control",
details.chkmultiarm = TRUE)
ssPainDurNMA
summary(ssPainDurNMA)

decomp.design(ssPainDurNMA)

ssPainDurNMA$trts

result.matrix \<- ssPainDurNMA$TE.random
result.matrix \<- round(result.matrix, 2)

result.matrix\[lower.tri(result.matrix, diag = FALSE)\] \<- NA

netleague \<- netleague(ssPainDurNMA,
bracket = "(", # use round brackets
digits=2)      # round to two digits

write.csv(netleague$random, file = "/Users/defiefendi/downloads/bismillah.csv")
```

I also try another syntax, but the result remain the same.

[image]

I have tried to follow number of examples from similar study. Also find books which provide syntax in R programming. I have follow their code and steps. The result remain incorrect.